# Can't install package bcmwl-kernel-source package

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

Need to get my wireless network adapter working on Ubuntu 14.1, but when trying to install the required package `bcmwl-kernel-source`, the "`apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`" installation command hangs on asking repetitively for a Ubuntu cdrom installation disk mount even after one is provided. Here is the exact terminal output that I am receiving:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source dkms
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,576 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,386 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter

Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

I tried mounting my installation cdrom as requested, but after pressing enter it seems that the installation unmounts the cdrom and loops back to request that I mount it again. Can't get out of this loop. Why does the installation of this package reqest an installation cd? Other packages install fine without requesting this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by disabling the option "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD" under the "Ubuntu Software" tab of the "Software and Applications" update tool.